Can a propane line be directed through an attic?
I have an old house partially sitting on a slab. I want to install a propane stove. The propane company came and said that because of the slab, they suggest installing the tank on the side of the house, in a spot which has access to the crawlspace under the kitchen. I'd rather not have a propane tank on the side of the house. There's an obvious and easy route for the pipes to go from the back of the house, through the attic and down to the kitchen. Would this be a reasonable request from me to the propane company? Any restrictions or code (Massachusetts, USA) issues regarding passing a propane line through an attic as opposed to a crawlspace?

If you are in Massachusetts, then you should be able to get the codes or restrictions easier than some of us as we may not be local to you...

Ask the propane company. They know what is and isn't possible/legal/a good idea. They'll default to the short/simple/least-cost to you/least bother for them option. If you want to give them more money they will figure a way to get it there from the back of the house that meets codes. Or you just bury a tank at the side of the house and it's not visible (but also costs more than a non-buried tank. Upside, works better in cold weather than an aboveground tank.)

Ask the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction -- in this case the office of your town's building inspector . They're the ones whose opinion matters, and they would much rather see the job done right than have to tell people to rip it out and do it again.

Yes, the propane company was able to install the propane line through the attic, and all inspections passed. They used black pipe, and the job was very expensive.
